# Neatly annotate forest plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I neatly annotate the four points in this forest plot using the "estimate" column? I would like them vertically aligned if possible.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(wesanderson)

## make data

df1 <- data.frame(matrix(, nrow=4, ncol=5))
colnames(df1) <- c("Metabolite", "OR", "CI_low", "CI_high", "Method")
df1$Metabolite <- c("Isoleucine", "Leucine", "Isoleucine", "Leucine")
df1$OR <- c(0.75, 0.64, 0.88, 0.95)
df1$CI_low <- c(0.61, 0.48, 0.8, 0.85)
df1$CI_high <- c(0.89, 0.8, 0.96, 1.05)
df1$Method <- c("Metabolomic", "Metabolomic", "GRS", "GRS")
df1$estimate <- c("0.75 (0.61, 0.89)", "0.64 (0.48, 0.8)",  "0.88 (0.8, 0.96)",  "0.95 (0.85, 1.05)")

# Plot using ggplot ------------------------------

ggplot(df1, aes(x=Metabolite, y=OR, ymin=CI_low, ymax=CI_high,col=Method,fill=Method)) + 
  #specify position here
  geom_linerange(size=1,position=position_dodge(width = 0.5), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, lty=2) +
  #specify position here too
  geom_point(size=3, shape=21, colour="white", stroke = 0.5,position=position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  # scale_fill_manual(values=barCOLS)+
  # scale_color_manual(values=dotCOLS)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette(name = "GrandBudapest2")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = wes_palette(name = "GrandBudapest2")) +
  scale_x_discrete(name="Metabolite") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Odds ratio (95% CI)", 
                     limits = c(0.4, 1.5), 
                     breaks = c(0.4, 1, 1.5),
                     labels=c("0.4", "1", "1.5")) +
  coord_flip() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: Who's W. E. Sanderson? ;-)

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FWes_Anderson&psig=AOvVaw0CPe40dbR6bof8oI4k6kNm&ust=1610202167387000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCNjpktbEjO4CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD

Answer (score 4):

How about a typical `geom_text()` with a dodge position?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(wesanderson)

## make data

df1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=4, ncol=5))
colnames(df1) <- c("Metabolite", "OR", "CI_low", "CI_high", "Method")
df1$Metabolite <- c("Isoleucine", "Leucine", "Isoleucine", "Leucine")
df1$OR <- c(0.75, 0.64, 0.88, 0.95)
df1$CI_low <- c(0.61, 0.48, 0.8, 0.85)
df1$CI_high <- c(0.89, 0.8, 0.96, 1.05)
df1$Method <- c("Metabolomic", "Metabolomic", "GRS", "GRS")
df1$estimate <- c("0.75 (0.61, 0.89)", "0.64 (0.48, 0.8)",  "0.88 (0.8, 0.96)",  "0.95 (0.85, 1.05)")

# Plot using ggplot ------------------------------

ggplot(df1, aes(x=Metabolite, y=OR, ymin=CI_low, ymax=CI_high,col=Method,fill=Method)) + 
  geom_linerange(size=1,position=position_dodge(width = 0.5), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, lty=2) +
  geom_point(size=3, shape=21, colour="white", stroke = 0.5,position=position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 0.8,label = estimate), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 1),
            show.legend = FALSE, hjust = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette(name = "GrandBudapest2")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = wes_palette(name = "GrandBudapest2")) +
  scale_x_discrete(name="Metabolite") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Odds ratio (95% CI)", 
                     limits = c(0.4, 1.5), 
                     breaks = c(0.4, 1, 1.5),
                     labels=c("0.4", "1", "1.5")) +
  coord_flip() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>